# Validar todos los campos de un formulario JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, formularios, dom

Tengo que hacer un programa con HTML y JavaScript, este es un formulario, **ya logre que verifique si es un correo**, al igual que los campos no esten vacios, pero **me falta, que al darle al boton de enviar, verifique todos los campos del formulario**, me refiero a que ninguno este vacio, intente muchas manera y ninguna funciona
ahora mismo mi programa puede hacer que nombre noe ste vacio, que valide si es un correo, que los dos coreos sean iguales, y que el mensaje tampoco este vacio, pero intento e intento y no encuentro la manera de hacer que el boton de enviar verifique que nada este vacio al presionarlo
puse un

```
  var checarTodo == document.getElementByID("botonenviar1")
    checarTodo.addEventListener("submit", checarTodoF,false)
   function checarTodoF(){
    correoVacio == document.getElementByID("botonenviar1").value
    if(correoVacio==""){
    alert("el correo no puede estar vacio")
}
```

pero esto no funciono, aunque ya habia hecho lo mismo para checar que mi espacio de nombre no estuviera vacio

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Formulario de registro</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="diseño.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Proyecto.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Formulario de mi proyecto!</h1>
        <form method="#" id="formularioRegistro">
            <input
                class="volver"
                type="button"
                onclick="location.href='Proyecto.html';"
                value="Volver"

            />
            <textarea
                name="Mensaje..."
                id="txtmensaje"
                class="mensaje"
                required:(maxlength="500"
                )
                placeholder=" Mensaje..."
            ></textarea>
            <input
                type="text"
                name="Nombre"
                id="txtnombre"
                class="nombre"
                placeholder=" Nombre..."
            />
            <input
                type="text"
                name="Email"
                id="txtcorreo"
                class="correo"
                placeholder=" Correo electronico"
            />
            <input
                type="text"
                name="confirmarEmail"
                id="txtConfirmarcorreo"
                class="confirmarEmail"
                placeholder="Confirmar correo electronico"
            />

            <input 
            type="submit" 
            name="Enviar formulario"
            id="botonEnviar1"
            class="botonEnviar"
             />
        </form>
        <div class="light x1"></div>
        <div class="light x2"></div>
        <div class="light x3"></div>
        <div class="light x4"></div>
        <div class="light x5"></div>
        <div class="light x6"></div>
        <div class="light x7"></div>
        <div class="light x8"></div>

    <div class="light x9"></div>
</body>
```

y aqui esta mi codigo de js

```
window.addEventListener("load", inicializarEventos, false);
function inicializarEventos() {
    var nombreFoco = document.getElementById("txtnombre");
    nombreFoco.addEventListener("blur", NombreVacio, false);
    var validarCorreo = document.getElementById("txtcorreo");
    validarCorreo.addEventListener("blur", validarCorreoF, false);
    var validarCorreo2 = document.getElementById("txtConfirmarcorreo");
    validarCorreo2.addEventListener("blur", validarCorreoF2, false);
    var validarMensaje = document.getElementById("txtmensaje");
    validarMensaje.addEventListener("blur", validarMensajeF, false)
    
}

function NombreVacio(e) {
    if (e.target.value == "") {
        alert("Ingrese un nombre, no puede estar vacio");
    }
}
function validarCorreoF() {
    var Correo = document.getElementById("txtcorreo").value;
    var expReg = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$/;
    var esValido = expReg.test(Correo);
    if (esValido == true) {
        alert("correo valido");
    } else {
        alert("correo invalido");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
var correoV = Correo;
var checar = esValido;
function validarCorreoF2() {
    var Correo2 = document.getElementById("txtConfirmarcorreo").value;
    var Correo = document.getElementById("txtcorreo").value;
    if (Correo2 == Correo){
        alert("Correos validos");
    }else{
        alert("Los correos deben ser iguales");
    }
    
}
function validarMensajeF(e) {
    if (e.target.value == ""){
        alert("El mensaje no puede estar vacio");
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes utilizar onsubmit para detectar el momento en que le dá al botón.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no conocia eso, ya investigue un poco y si me funciono